# How can I set the version of a NuGet nuspec <dependency> from the command-line?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I have a Windows batch file that builds several `*.csproj` projects and then creates NuGet packages from the outputs using a manually maintained `*.nuspec` file.

- The batch file starts by using `set /p packver="Enter semver package version"` and then using `nuget [...] --version %packver%` so that all of the output packages have the same version.
- The first NuGet package, `MyCompany.Gadget`, is self-contained
- The second NuGet package, `MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions`, is dependent on the first package - and I want the output package to also be dependent on the specified version of `MyCompany.Gadget`.

  - I have a `<dependencies><dependency id="MyCompany.Gadget" version="1.2.3" />` in the `MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions.nuspec` file.
  - This is a pain to manually maintain as I have to pause the script and manually enter it into the `nuspec` file by hand - though I now use `rxrepl.exe` to update the version number from the `%packver%` environment variable.

I didn't see any `nuget.exe` command-line options for `nuget pack` to specify an explicit version. I imagine it might be possible using the `-Properties` option, but I don't know how to set `<dependency version="..." />` values using that, or if it's possible at all.

Is there a better approach?

(Here is a fuller example of my batch script; my hack is the `rxrepl.exe` line near the end):

```
@echo off
echo Enter semver version number for the MyCompany.Gadget packages (e.g. '2.0.0-beta1' or '2.0.1'): 

set /p packver="Semver package version number: "

@echo on

REM -----------------------
REM Build MyCompany.Gadget
REM -----------------------

msbuild ..\Gadget\MyCompany.Gadget.csproj -property:Configuration=Release

mkdir MyCompany.Gadget
copy ..\Gadget\bin\Release\Gadget.dll MyCompany.Gadget\lib\net472\Gadget.dll
copy ..\Gadget\bin\Release\Gadget.pdb MyCompany.Gadget\lib\net472\Gadget.pdb
copy ..\Gadget\bin\Release\Gadget.xml MyCompany.Gadget\lib\net472\Gadget.xml

nuget pack MyCompany.Gadget.nuspec -BasePath MyCompany.Gadget -outputDirectory Out -version %packver% -symbols -Properties Configuration=Release;

REM -----------------------
REM Build MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions
REM -----------------------

msbuild ..\Gadget\MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions.csproj -property:Configuration=Release

mkdir MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions
copy ..\Gadget\bin\Release\Gadget.dll MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions\lib\net472\Gadget.dll
copy ..\Gadget\bin\Release\Gadget.pdb MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions\lib\net472\Gadget.pdb
copy ..\Gadget\bin\Release\Gadget.xml MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions\lib\net472\Gadget.xml

REM Update the <dependency> version number:
rxrepl.exe --file MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions.nuspec --alter --search "<dependency id=""MyCompany.Gadget""\s+version=""([^""]+)"" />" --replace "<dependency id=""MyCompany.Gadget"" version=""%packver%"" />"

nuget pack MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions.nuspec -BasePath MyCompany.Gadget.Extensions -outputDirectory Out -version %packver% -symbols -Properties Configuration=Release;
```

Comment: Why don't you pack the csproj and let NuGet add the dependencies automatically? If your projects are SDK style (can target either .NET Core or .NET Framework), then you don't even need a nuspec. Let NuGet do it all automatically.

Comment: @zivkan Well, right now the `MyCompany.Gadget` package actually contains binaries for `net35`, `net461` and `net472` - I do this by running `msbuild MyCompany.Gadget.csproj` three times (with different `-property:Configuration=` values) and copying the output into the NuGet `lib` folders then using the `nuspec` file. I don't believe that's possible with `nuget pack MyCompany.Gadget.csproj` - at least not without really customizing the MSBuild steps in the csproj.

Comment: If you migrate to an SDK style project, you just have `<TargetFrameworks>net35;net461;net472</TargetFrameworks>` in a single csproj, then run `dotnet pack`, and it'll work. (nuget pack only "works" for projects using packages.config. any project using PackageReference should use `dotnet pack` or `msbuild /t:pack`)

Comment: @zivkan You can use an SDK-style project to target .NET Framework 3.5? Wow. Is Fx 2.0 and Fx 1.1 supported too?

Comment: [Newtonsoft.Json targets net20](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/7b8c3b0ed0380cf76d66894e81bf4d4d5b0bd796/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj#L3). But honestly, why? they're so far out of support. Who are your customers that you imagine need 1.1, 2.0 or 3.5 and why can't they update to 4.7.2, or at least 4.5? You incur technical debt needing to support these ancient versions. What benefit is there for the ongoing cost?

Comment: @zivkan Ah - no - I was just curious at Fx1.1 and Fx20 support - 3.5 is the oldest i need to support.

Comment: @zivkan Looking at the documentation for referencing projects that have their own packages - it looks like they **have** to have their own `*.nuspec` files - I can't rely on only `.csproj` files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.5#Improved_project_reference_support_for_NuGet.exe_Pack

Comment: `nuget pack` is only if your project uses `packages.config`. If your project uses `PackageReference`, which all SDK projects do, you should use the pack targets (either `msbuild -t:pack`, or `dotnet pack`). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format